# Probability that exactly two engines are working

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have a ship with $3$ engines and for ship to function atleast $2$ engines must be working. Probability which decides if engine is working is given as

- $P(E_1)=\frac{1}{2}$
- $P(E_2)=\frac{1}{4}$
- $P(E_3)=\frac{1}{4}$

Then what is probability that exactly two of them are working?

I thing Probability should be given by $$P(X)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2}$$ 
but this does't matches with correct answer , what's wrong here?

Comment: What would happen if all three engines are working? Did you account for that too?

Comment: I don't need to , I just calculated probability that one has failed and other are working.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the latest version of your question correctly. What is the 'correct' answer then?

Comment: I mean exactly two of them

Comment: $\frac{7}{8}$ , could they asking if exactly two engines are working and ship is also working?

Comment: From the answer given, it seems that they want to find the conditional probability of exactly two engines working given that the ship is also working.

Comment: Yes. P(exact 2 working | the ship is running) = (7/32) / (8/32).